# Magento 2 Can't submit custom form with custom controller-action in admin order detail page

Tags: magento2, adminform, edit-order

I am creating custom form in admin order detail page with form action as like below but it's redirecting to Dashboard from my action with 302.

My script is:

sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_additional_info">
        <block class="Sample\Serialcode\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Pdf" name="sales_order_view_pdf" template="order/view/pdf.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

Phtml file:

```
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('sample/serialcode/index/');?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="orderid"  class="orderid" value="<?php //echo $incrementId?>"/>
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="ishasparent" class="ishasparent" value=""/>
         <input type="hidden" name="sku" class="sku" value=""/>
         <input type="hidden" name="parentsku" class="parentsku" value=""/>
         <input type="hidden" name="missedSerialcodes" class="missedSerialcodes" value=""/>-->
        <label>Serial Codes </label><textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="newserialcodes"></textarea>
        <p style="color: red;display: none">Serial Codes are not empty</p>
        <p>Note: Each serial code seperated by '|' symbol like "121|122|123"</p>
        <button type="submit" class="form-submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Block File:

```
namespace Sample\Serialcode\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;

 use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;


 class Pdf extends Template
 {

protected $order;

protected $orderitemSerialcode;

protected $orderData;

public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
                            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
                            \Sample\Serialcode\Model\OrderitemSerialcode $orderitemSerialcode,
                            array $data = [])
{
    $this->orderData = array();
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->orderitemSerialcode = $orderitemSerialcode;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

 }
```

My Controller:

```
namespace Sample\Serialcode\Controller\Adminhtml\Serialcode;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;


class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action{


    protected $orderObj;

    private $coreRegistry = null;

    private $resultPageFactory;

    private $backSession;

    protected $sage;

    public function __construct(Action\Context $context,
                                \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
                                \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
                               ){

        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->backSession = $context->getSession();

        parent::__construct($context);

    }


    public function execute(){
        echo  "hello";exit;           
    }
  }
```

routes.xml

Sample\Serialcode\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route id="sample" frontName="sample">
        <module name="Sample_Serialcode" />
    </route>
</router>
```

When i used this url for menu it's redirection but it's not working from order detail page

Comment: can you please update your question with routes.xml, please share path of this file as well.

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar, i update code will you please check once & When i used this url for menu it's redirection but it's not working from order detail page

Comment: @Ramkishan, sorry to say that's my typing issue in editor. if i used same action from menu action it's redirecting...it's not working from order detail page

Comment: Have you tried the solution which I have given below?

Comment: yes @RamkishanSuthar....

Answer (score 3):

@ Thanks Ramkishan Suthar

This is the issue with form key.

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php / @escapeNotVerified / echo $block->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update routes.xml like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route id="sample" frontName="sample">
        <module name="Sample_Serialcode" />
    </route>
</router>
```

Your module name should not start with lowercase. Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: This is the issue with form key